# Form doesn't work inside fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, fancybox, prestashop

I have a form that works just fine when I [try it out](http://jsfiddle.net/Trufa/hQENa/1/) (with the correct address of course).

When I use that for in my site, inside a fancybox it doesn't work. Nothing happens (no error in the console either).

The relevant code is:

```
<a class="fancybox" href="#inline1" id="link_consultar">
  Consultar
</a>
<div style="display: none">
  <div id="inline1">
    Producto: {$product->
    name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}
    <br>
    <br>
    <form id="myForm" action="http://danielvi.com/send_mail.php" method="post">
      Nombre: 
      <input type="text" name="firstname">
      <br>
      <br>
      Consulta:
      <br>
      <textarea rows="4" cols="50">
      </textarea>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Enviar Consulta" />

    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

The JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myForm').submit(function(){
        alert("submitted");
    });
});
```

I have also tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myForm").on("submit", function(event){
        alert("submitted");
    });        
});
```

I have included the form plugin like this:

```
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

With no success, the end goal is to send form by AJAX, this is a simplified example to debug.

What I don't understand either is that even when I remove all js it wont direct me to the action page.

You can see a live example [here](http://danielvi.com/index.php?id_product=1&controller=product&id_lang=4) (When you click consulta).

Comment: It is because of the missing `<form>` on the live example.

Comment: @PranavKapoor I've updated and still nothing... Sorry about that.

Comment: Still cannot see it. Try `$('#fancybox-wrap').find('form')` on the console after clicking the button.

Comment: @PranavKapoor the form seems to be inside another form which seems to be the problem, I'll check back ASAP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is shown on your live site. Upon examining the source code, you can see that you're adding a form within another form

```
<form id="buy_block"  action="http://danielvi.com/index.php?controller=cart" method="post">
    [...]
    <form id="myForm" action="http://danielvi.com/send_mail.php" method="post">
         [...]
    </form>
</form>
```

Which invalidates the second form you're working with. That is why it's not doing anything. Other than that, the code is valid.

Comment: Hmm that seems to be the problem, I'll report back ASAP!

Comment: @Trufa In the future, you can test validate your source code over at [W3C MVS](http://validator.w3.org/), either by site or by file. I noticed the problem because Firefox marks invalid markup red when viewing source code. You should try and get familiar with the debugging tools available. :)

Answer (score 1):

On the [live site](http://danielvi.com/index.php?id_product=1&controller=product&id_lang=4), you seem to be missing the `<form>` element in the `#fancybox-content`.

Comment: I've just inspected the element and you're right, but when I just see the code I actually see it, fancybox seems to be removing the form tags????? See here http://i.imgur.com/CV8tV.png I'm 100% sure the form tag is there in the original code.

Comment: This is actually a correct answer so +1 and thanks, I accpted @ShadowScripter's answer simply because he pointed out that it was a form inside a form and that lead me to find the problem thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You've got the contact form inside form#buy_block which is invalid. Try moving the whole `<div id="inline1">` outside of the `<form id="buy_block`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[type='submit']").click(function(){
    $.ajax: {
        type     : "POST",
        cache    : false,
        url      : "http://danielvi.com/send_mail.php",
        success: function(data) {
            $.fancybox({
                'width': 400,
                'height': 400,
                'enableEscapeButton' : false,
                'overlayShow' : true,
                'overlayOpacity' : 0,
                'hideOnOverlayClick' : false,
                'content' : data
            });
        }
    }
});
```